# Breadboard to perfboard

Tags: arduino, soldering, breadboard, piezo

Update:
Thanks all! Problem solved. I tried to connect all the resistors to the ground and it did work!

---

I'm having a problem regarding a circuit on a perfboard. I try to use five piezo sensors which send MIDI messages to my Max Patch. I first did the setup on the breadboard and it worked well. Then I tried to move all I did to a perfboard, but it didn't work (see the pics).

I understand the perfboard doesn't have the connections between each point so I connected using solder/jumper wires. I can see there are a bunch of MIDI messages running automatically on hairless MIDI without touching the piezo. Maybe something is wrong with the soldering.

Could anyone help me with this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks all! Problem solved. I tried to connect all the resistors to the ground and it did work!

Answer (score 4):

> I can see there are a bunch of midi messages running automatically on hairless midi without touching the piezo

This sounds like there may be some "floating pins" (especially if the messages are happening randomly) and it looks like you are using pull-down resistors (which are connected to your wires that go to your Arduino inputs) which is good. However, I think it works on the breadboard and not on the perfboard because your pull-down resistors aren't connected to ground (so your pins are floating)!

[image: Photo of perfboard]

Can you try connecting/soldering the ends of the resistors (red arrows) to ground (green circle)?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the other end of the resistors to ground. I don't see any other problem here other than that. If that doesn't work then try soldering wires at the back of the perfboard instead of solder patches